# Using NLog with multiple servers. Want to write to 1 file on a specific server

Tags: nlog

I have a asp.net mvc application using nLog that is deployed on 3 servers, lets call them webserver1, webserver2, and webserver3.   Currently each writes the log file to the base directory/app date/ directory.  I would like to have only one log on a specific server(not the webservers).  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You might be able to configure a File target to log to a file specified by URL.  Not really sure this would work for two reasons:  First, not sure that that you can specify a filename by URL.  Second, not sure it's a good idea to have multiple processes logging to the same logging to the same file.
2. Better option...  Use the [DatabaseTarget](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Database_target) to send your log messages to a database.
3. Even better option(??)... Use the [NLogReceiverServiceTarget](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/LogReceiverService_target) to log to an NLogReceiverService (WCF service).  The NLogReceiverService WCF service is really just another "application" that "logs" with NLog, so its logging destination (Target) can be configured however you like (log to a file, database, etc).